# What was this 7th Doctor novel?

Tags: story-identification, doctor-who, novel

I remember reading a Virgin Doctor Who novel where the 7th Doctor ended by stringing up the 5th Doctor on a tree (?) because the 5th Doctor had somehow betrayed the fraternity or something similar. That is about all l have apart from the half remembered impression that it was a ripper of a read!

Comment: Although this one has been answered, there's one where the 5th and 7th Doctors actually meet in real life (i.e. not in the depths of Seven's psyche/unconscious mind.) It's called "Cold Fusion". Though IIRC there was a lot more of Five than Seven, and they didn't meet up until very near the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe **Timewyrm: Revelation?**

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Timewyrm:_Revelation

I haven't read it, but I found a reference to the seventh doctor **chaining up** the fifth doctor in his own psyche as the fifth doctor was his conscience, and then found a reference to the fifth doctor serving as conscience in the minds of future doctors with a reference to this book.

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fifth_Doctor ("Influence on later incarnations" contains the paragraph which links this novel).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_Doctor ("in his psyche, [the seventh doctor] chained up the Fifth Doctor, who served as his conscience." under the subheading "Viewed by other incarnations")

Comment: That's the one! Brilliant! :)